# Rails CSV generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, export-to-csv

How can I add data to a csv file by column rather than row.

What I currently have:

```
  def self.as_csv(rating_id)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["set_id","item_id", "aggregated_rating", "related_item_id", "rating", "time"]
      product_ids = RatingSet.find(rating_id).products
      product_ids.each do |product|
       recommendation_ids =Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products, :conditions => ["product_id = ? and rating_set = ?", product.id, rating_id])
        recommendation_ids.each do |recommendation|
          Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["recommendation_id = ? and rating_set = ? and product_id = ?", recommendation.id, rating_id, product.id]).each do |rating|
           time_updated = (rating.updated_at)
            csv <<  [rating_id, product.id, product.rating, recommendation.id, rating.rating, time_updated]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This basically generate new rows for each set of data, example:

```
102 4433175 2.4 10391793    1   2013-03-26 18:33:40 UTC 
102 4433175 2.4 10391794    1   2013-03-26 18:33:40 UTC 
102 4433175 2.4 12526899    1   2013-03-26 18:33:40 UTC 
102 4433175 2.4 19235377    1   2013-03-26 18:33:40 UTC
```

How can I generate it by adding new columns rather than rows:

```
102 4433175 2.4 10391793    1   10391794    1   12526899    1   19235377    1   2013-03-26 18:33:41 UTC
```

Comment: If you can construct an array, you can construct a CSV row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group_by`.

If performance isn't an issue, you could also do

```
 def self.as_csv(rating_id)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["set_id","item_id", "aggregated_rating", "related_item_id", "rating", "time"]
      product_ids = RatingSet.find(rating_id).products
      product_ids.each do |product|
       recommendation_ids =Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products, :conditions => ["product_id = ? and rating_set = ?", product.id, rating_id])
        recommendation_ids.each do |recommendation|
          rattings = Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["recommendation_id = ? and rating_set = ? and product_id = ?", recommendation.id, rating_id, product.id]).map { |r| [r.ratting, r.updated_at] }.flatten
            csv << ([rating_id, product.id, product.rating, recommendation.id] + rattings)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```